# GA Page View tracking with additional information

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a site where users login to access technical information. Before accessing the information, they also have to enter a set of filter options. Different filter options result in different information displayed on different pages but the url is the same.

For example, a user will get the following URL when accessing a specific document, regardless of what filter options set:
www.site.com/fr/category/document/

Depending on the filter options, different sections of the document will be visible.

Currently, no information in GA tells us what filters were used when visiting the page. We do not want to add filter parameters to the URL. At least not for the visitor, but maybe add it in the tracking somehow?

What would be the optimal/correct way to track that kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution may depends how your site works etc. But how about using custom dimensions assigned to "hit" (pageview) scope? Maybe they will help in your case? Documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets (code in documentation depends how your GA is implemented of course). Thanks to them you can send with pageviews hit additional (custom) information (e.g which filters were used).

Other way could be just sending google analytics event (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) with information which filters were used before pageview hit. Then just in Google Analytics panel you can create custom segment with sequence where 2 events occurred:

1. Click (or use filters) - event
2. See specific URL - pageview

Or of course you can implement both solutions (custom dimensions for pageview and events).

Comment: The custom dimensions looks like what I'm searching for. Thank you!